# Should I upgrade RAM or to a SSD?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, ssd, memory

Ok, I have a late 2011 macbook pro that I'm looking to upgrade. It's sluggish with basic tasks such as right clicking to open the little options menu thingy (like the copy and past menu) and minimizing windows and stuff. I mostly just use my macbook for lots and lots of Internet browsing... And I mean lots (I currently have 20 tabs open on 3 different windows of Google chrome) and I also watch quite a bit of netflix and youtube (but when I'm not watching those I don't have it open in a tab so that shouldn't be that big of a problem). So should I upgrade my RAM from 4 GB to 8 GB or should I upgrade my 500 GB HDD to a 512 GB SSD? Thanks for looking!

Comment: I have one anecdote: a 2008 white MacBook with 2GB of RAM was performing really poorly under Mavericks. An SSD update brought big performance improvements, it became perfectly usable as a development machine. UI-latency-wise it was better than a brand new i5 iMac. A further doubling of RAM lowered the wear on the SSD. So, if you have 4GB of RAM, the SSD upgrade will bring most noticeable improvement. A 128GB SSD will be plenty, just replace the optical drive with a hard drive caddy. That should be most bang for the buck - for around $100 you can have excellent performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your budget (512GB SSD is quite expensive) I'd buy 8GB RAM + 256SSD and keep the 500GB HDD as a storage volume instead of the super drive. Depending on your country, it'll cost you around 200$ which is less expensive than a 500SSD and will bring you a lot of speed.

Comment: Due to the length of the bread, comments have been moved to a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17908/discussion-on-answer-by-thomas-should-i-upgrade-ram-or-to-a-ssd); please continue the discussion there.